# How to set up iptables for LDAP on Fedora

Tags: iptables, ldap, 389-ds

I am running 389 Directory Server on Fedora 14. When I use ldapsearch to connect to myserver.com:389 from localhost, it works fine. When I use ldapsearch to connect to myserver.com:389 from a different computer on the network and I have iptables running on the server, ldapsearch cannot connect to the server. When I turn off iptables on the server, ldapsearch on the other computer does connect to the server.

My iptables file is as follows:

```
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
-A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -p icmp -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 --tcp-flags SYN,RST,ACK SYN -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 --tcp-flags SYN,RST,ACK SYN -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited 
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 389 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -p udp -m udp --dport 389 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT 
-A FORWARD -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited 
-A OUTPUT -p tcp -m tcp --sport 389 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT 
-A OUTPUT -p udp -m udp --sport 389 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT 
COMMIT
```

How should I fix my iptables so that I can run LDAP?

Answer (score 1):

You need to reorder the rules

`-A INPUT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited`

precedes the allow lines

`-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 389 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT`

`-A INPUT -p udp -m udp --dport 389 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT`

move "-A INPUT -j REJECT -reject-with icmp-host-prohibited " below the ACCEPT lines I mentioned and reload firewall.

you can try iptables-save > firewall

edit file firewall, move line as I suggested, save , exit

iptables-restore < firewall

voila.